# Further doping p-type material. Why doesn't this increase the hole mobility. etc?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, solar-cells

I did a project in which I made perovksite nanocrystal solar cells. The hole transport material was doped with another p-type material and performance was compared. It turns out that this didn't actually improve performance.

After doing this I realised I'm missing some basic physics and I can't really explain why I think doping should increase the performance (in this case, holes through the hole transport layer).

My vague ideas are that doping changes the band gaps and this could be done so unfavourably, such that less holes will travel through the material from the active layer.

Secondly, perhaps the electron transport layer also needs to be improved before a higher current is observed through both layers, as the electron transport layer could be ultimately limiting the performance.

I think I'm confused about the fundamental idea of, why is it that further doping a p-type material should increase the hole conductivity through it. Is this even something that can be stated, or is this much more complicated?

Thank you greatly for any help with this. Please let me know if there are some additional details that are needed, I've tried to provide the relevant points.

Comment: Conductivity is a combination of how many carriers you have available (which doping increases) and how easily they move (which doping usually decreases through increased scattering). If the doping is so high that it materially changes the band structure, well, it isn't doping any more...

Comment: Thank you so much, that is incredibly helpful. What exactly is this scattering, and why exactly does it happen? I would like to read more about that. In my (short) project, I tried doping with different concentrations, anywhere from 0.005% (w/w) to 1% (w/w). I imagine the 1% definitely changed the band structure. Is it possible to tell at which point below this it would be "doping" then? Or is this not possible to know?

Comment: Doping increases scattering because (a) the dopant atoms, although incorporated in the crystal, are not the same as the host atoms (so, e.g., strain is increased locally) and (b) ionized dopant atoms are charged, increasing their scattering cross section. By changing the band structure I mean really changing things like the (in your case) valence band, effective mass, etc., which even 1% likely isn't going to do.